# when jquery, javascript functions are called?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When HTML page is open, I can call javascript function with many ways.(automatically)
`onpageshow`, `onload`, `$(function() {...} );`, only simple line function, etc..

I want to know what are different and sequence of them.
(Recently, I understand `onload` don't called if the page is caching, so i change it `onpageshow`).

[Number] in under code is the sequence that I expected.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onpageshow="onPageShow();" onload="onLoad()">

<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("[1] - simple function");

  function onPageShow() {
    console.log("[2] - onPageShow()");
  }

  function onLoad() {
    console.log("[3] - onLoad()");
  }

  $(function() {
    console.log(`[4] - $(function(){})`);
    // same with document.onload, maybe
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You might also be interested in [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) and [`readystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event). See http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### OnLoad()

The `onload` event occurs when an object has been loaded. Onload is most often used within the  element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content *(including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).*

**Example (in HTML)**

```html
<element onload="myScript">
```

**Example (in JavaScript)**

```js
object.onload = function(){myScript};
```

#### OnPageShow()

The onpageshow event occurs when a user navigates to a webpage. The onpageshow event is similar to the onload event, except that it occurs after the onload event when the page first loads. Also, the onpageshow event occurs every time the page is loaded, whereas the onload event does not occur when the page is loaded from the cache.

**Example:**

```js
<body onpageshow="myFunction()">
```

Comment: For make short `html` code, I use `onpageshow` not `onload`. because `onload` sometimes don't drawing my data-elements. like this situation, Is there any advantages `onload` is better than `onpageshow`?

Answer (score 0):

**Onload Event**

The DOM onload event in HTML occurs when an object has been loaded. The onload event is mostly used within the element, The `<body>`

The onload event can be used to check the browser type and browser version, and load the version of the web page based on the information. The onload event can also be used for cookies.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>
   HTML DOM onload Event
</title>
</head>

<body>
 <center>
     <img src="https://contribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/GeeksforGeeksLogoHeader.png" 
         id="imgid">
    <p id="pid"></p>

    <script>
        document.getElementById(
          "imgid").addEventListener("load", GFGFun);

        function GFGFun() {
            document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML = 
              "Image loaded";
        }
    </script>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

**OnPageShow Event**

The DOM onpageshow event in HTML occurs on navigating a webpage by the user.

the onload event does not occur when the page is loaded from the cache and onpageshow event occurs every time the page is loaded otherwise both the events are similar.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>
     HTML DOM onpageshow Event
 </title>
</head>

<body>
 <center>
     <h1 id="hID" 
         style="color:green">
     </h1>
    
     <h2>HTML DOM onpageshow Event</h2>
 </center>

<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName(
      "BODY")[0].onpageshow = function() {
        GFGfun()
    };

    function GFGfun() {
        document.getElementById("hID").innerHTML =
          "GeeksforGeeks";
    };
 </script>

</body>

</html>
```