# How to block my question code to snippset?

Tags: markdown

I don't know this subject can upload in here.
How can I attach my code with `snippset`?

When I wrote question, other people edit my question with snippset.
I'm so sorry everytime when other people edit my question, so I'm going to ask with snippset code myself.

````cpp
//  ```c++
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        cout << "This is what I know to make code-block" << endl;
    }
//  ```
````

How can I attach my code with run snippset?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and improve it.

Comment: My Question is very simple. How to attach my code with `Run Snippset`.

Comment: What is "Run Snippset"? (Even if you mean "Run Snippet" I still don't understand.) And what does it have to do with Markdown? Why are you showing us C++ code?

Comment: [Node.js Question sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849086/when-jquery-javascript-functions-are-called/) like this question, sometimes people attach codes runnable. I don't know these skills are classified, so I take markdown tags. Sorry for few informations.

Comment: Ah. See [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/354577) This isn't for arbitrary languages, though. I'm pretty sure you can't do it for C++.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for reply all of my messages. If you think this question is not appropriated, I'll delete this post. Anyway, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet feature is only available for HTML, CSS and JavaScript. That's due to the fact that these languages run directly on your browser, in an individual sandbox. So, in hindsight, you cannot do this for C++ code.

If you'd want to add snippets however, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> or click the snippet button on the toolbar. You can write you codes there, and it'll look like this:

```js
function demo() {
  var a = Number(document.getElementById("A").value);
  var b = Number(document.getElementById("B").value);
  var sum = a + b;
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
  color: #E5E3E5;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.content {
  width: fit-content;
  /* margin-left: auto; */
  /* margin-right: auto; */
}

.inputDiv {
  display: block;
}

input {
  background-color: #E5E3E5;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 2px 20px;
}

input:hover {
  border: solid #566524;
}

input:active,
input:focus {
  border: solid #90AF2D;
}

.do {
  border: none;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  float: right;
}

.do:hover {
  opacity: 80%;
  border: none;
}

.do:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

#sum {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Simple HTML, CSS, JS</h1>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <label for="A">A</label>
      <input type="number" name="A" id="A">
    </div>
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <label for="B">B</label>
      <input type="number" name="B" id="B">
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="do" value="Add" onclick="demo()">
    <div>
      <h2>
        Sum
      </h2>
      <label id="sum"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What you can do is to copy your code to an online compiler/IDE and share the link. The problem with embedding that code snippet, even as a runnable `iframe` like [trinket.io](https://trinket.io/python) does for python or in a `script` like [onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) does, is that they are essentially external sources that load in external, uncontrolled data, and also are prone to being lost in time and not be available in the future. So StackExchange does not really allow them natively.

If you are insistent though, you can just use those snippets in the same runnable block, like this:

```html
<script src="//onlinegdb.com/embed/js/rJlgvcqWHu?theme=dark"></script>
```

But it's still problematic at best. Some users will be hesitant to click on external links, and some users' browsers might even block them.